# Python tkinter - remove additional window - tk.withdraw() already called

Tags: python, tkinter, window

I am writing a little program which, in some cases, opens two different file explorers in series.

At first the user is allowed to select a folder. If that doesent suit him, he can close that file explorer window and another one, which allows the user to select specific files, will open.

Just as the second file explorer opens, a tkinter window does also.
I already called tk.withdraw() bevore the first explorer-call.

Here is the code fragment which produces the trouble:

```
def get_input_files():

    root = Tk()
    root.withdraw()

    input_files = get_input_folders_with_file_browser(root) # let the user select files through the file browser

    if len(input_files) == 0:   # if not files where selected

        input_files = get_input_files_with_file_browser(root)

    input_files = list(input_files)

    for file in input_files:

        if os.path.isdir(file):

            for sub_file in os.listdir(file):

                sub_file = os.path.join(file, sub_file)

                input_files.append(sub_file)

    return input_files


def get_input_files_with_file_browser(root):

    try:
        root.iconbitmap(default ='data/Logo/LogoCut_image.ico') # Set icon of the file explorer
    except:

        draw_line()
        print("No icon for file explorer found.")
        draw_line()


    working_dir = os.getcwd()   # Get working dir

    filenames = filedialog.askopenfilenames(initialdir = working_dir , title ="Choose your files!", filetypes = (('.jpg files', '*.jpg'),("All files", '*')))
    files = Tk().tk.splitlist(filenames)    # to array

    return files


def get_input_folders_with_file_browser(root):

    try:
        root.iconbitmap(default ='data/Logo/LogoCut_image.ico') # Set icon of the file explorer
    except:

        draw_line()
        print("No icon for file explorer found.")
        draw_line()


    working_dir = os.getcwd()   # Get working dir

    filenames = filedialog.askdirectory(initialdir = working_dir , title ="Choose your folders!")
    files = Tk().tk.splitlist(filenames)    # to array

    return files
```

I tried calling it some more times in diffrent locations in the code, but the additional window keeps showing itself.

Does anyone have an idea how i am able to hide the additional window?

- Hoping for some good answers.

Fabian

Comment: We can’t help if we can’t see your code. Please include a [mcve] in your question.

Comment: My guess is that you are creating a second tkinter.Tk() window.  You withdraw the first, then create another.  But I second Bryan's request.